# Malformed utmcc in utm.gif request

Tags: javascript, asp.net, configuration, cookies, google-analytics

I have a page that is using Google Analytics to track page views as well as track events within the page. The initial _gat._trackPageview request works as intended (under normal circumstances, details to follow). However, on subsequent `utm.gif` requests, it seems there is a malformed `utmcc` argument in the querystring. The campaign tracking is missing:

Malformed:

```
utmcc=__utma%3D198519536.1306122932.1283860172.1283860172.1283860172.1%3B
```

Normal:

```
utmcc=__utma%3D198519536.1779782135.1283862963.1283862963.1283862963.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D198519536.1283862963.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B
```

Looking at my cookies, `__utmz` seems to be correctly formed in both cases:

```
198519536.1283862963.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

Now, the odd thing is that this bug seems to occur somewhere between the initial page track, and the time when the user interacts with the page; `_gat._trackEvent` is affected by it.

It gets even stranger when we consider that I've tested the exact same code on another server, and it behaves correctly - the `utmcc` data is maintained across page views.

Things I've considered:

- **cookie conflicts** - this is refuted by the test on the other server
- **global variable conflicts** - the GA code does not seem to expose any globals that affect the utm.gif call.
- **Server configuration** - I'm working under ASP.NET, and there seems to be no meaningful difference between the live server (where the problem is occurring) and the test server (where the problem is not)
- **ASP.NET Script Resources conflicting** - I don't know how to test for this, or what to do about it if this turns out to be the issue
- **Redirects** - This page *does* use redirects under certain circumstances, and I know there can be issues with that, but the issue seems to be occurring only when we *don't* redirect. Also, it seems to be occurring within the page load.

Has anybody run into this issue before? Have you encountered similar situations? Is it something I can avoid in the future?

Comment: Never did figure this one out. We removed the A/B test, and the problem went away.